# Taskbar manual popup in full screen

Tags: windows, powershell, operating-system

So I want to make my taskbar popup whenever I am in my browser full screen. Like I am watching a YT video, I hover in the taskbar region(bottom screen) for few seconds and task bar pop ups. Like I am using autohide task bar, So normally it is hidden, but whenever I hover below, it pop ups. I would like to do it also in full screen.

I tried ChatGPT and it suggested me to create and run a PowerShell script. It gave me this script:

```
# Function to show the taskbar
Function Show-Taskbar {
    param([int]$delay)

    # Send the Windows key to show the taskbar
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $wshell.SendKeys('^{ESC}')

    # Wait for the taskbar to appear
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $delay

    # Minimize any fullscreen application if it's active
    $wshell.SendKeys('%{SPACE}n')
}

# Call the function with a delay of 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds)
Show-Taskbar -delay 2000
```

It didn't work. Can someone tell me how can I achieve it? Like I want to popup the taskbar so how can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried yourself (apart from asking ChatGPT, e.g. are you able to detect the browser? And whether this is full screen? or any of the implied tasks as handeling the taskbar?). Note this is *not* a script factory. You will need to write the script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers, you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)